# Read raw compressed buffer from file.jpg using jpeglib

Tags: c++, jpeg, image-compression, libjpeg

I am looking to write a code to open a `file.jpg` and load the data into a buffer without actually decompressing the data. I need to send the data as is.

I have found a [code](https://github.com/LuaDist/libjpeg/blob/master/example.c#L284) that reads an image and decompresses it. I don't know how to modify the code to just get the raw bytes not decompressed version.

```
  struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
  struct my_error_mgr jerr;
  FILE * infile;        /* source file */
  JSAMPARRAY buffer;        /* Output row buffer */
  int row_stride;       /* physical row width in output buffer */

  if ((infile = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", filename);
    return 0;
  }

  /* Now we can initialize the JPEG decompression object. */
  jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);

  /* Step 2: specify data source (eg, a file) */
  jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, infile);

  (void) jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);

  // Here I want to only get raw bytes
  (void) jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);

  row_stride = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_components;
  /* Make a one-row-high sample array that will go away when done with image */
  buffer = (*cinfo.mem->alloc_sarray)
        ((j_common_ptr) &cinfo, JPOOL_IMAGE, row_stride, 1);

  while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height) {

    (void) jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, buffer, 1);
    /* Assume put_scanline_someplace wants a pointer and sample count. */
    // put_scanline_someplace(buffer[0], row_stride);
  }

  /* Step 7: Finish decompression */

  (void) jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);      

  jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);

  fclose(infile);
```

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to send the complete jpg file or just the encoded data portion of the file? Note that in the second case the encoded data may be useless without the information contained within the rest of the file.

Comment: @user4581301 I want to send the whole encoded data including header.

Comment: In that case consider something like: `std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);std::vector<char>((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());` The whole dile sits in the vector and you can access it as a `vector` or as an array of `char`  through the `data` method.

Comment: @user4581301
Does it need me to know the data size in advance?

Comment: @user4581301 Well now make it an answer, but don't forget `std::vector::reserve()`. :)

Comment: Depending on how you get the file size, it may be more expensive than the `vector` resizes. I'm all for keeping it simple for now. Rather than formally answer, I'm going dupe hunting.

Comment: You know what? I can't find a good dupe. All of them seem to have an option where they try to reserve space and get the file size wrong.

Comment: Huh? If you don't want to decode the file and you just want to send it *"as is"*, you don't need `libjpeg` at all. Just open in binary mode, read, close - 3 lines.

Comment: @MarkSetchell You are right. I just made it work without using libjpeg. 
I needed to stat input file for size though.

Comment: Cool. Or you can `seek()` to the end, use `ftell()` to get the position (which is the size) and then `seek()` back to the start. Either way.

Comment: I've had the `seek` to the end trick fail on me before. Reading to the end always works, but is slow and kind-of stupid. `ignore`ing to the end is similar. Haven't played with the filesystem library yet, but I expect it to be similar to using system-specific calls..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exchanging comments below the question post, it turned out that if we don't care about decompression, simple byte reading would suffice. Here is the code that solved the problem:

```
char* data = (char*)malloc(max_w*max_h*3 +100); 

if (data == NULL) {
    printf("Input data must not be NULL.\n");
    return 0;
}

FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb"); /* b - binary mode */
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file %s\n", filename);
    return 0;
}

struct stat filestatus;
stat(filename, &filestatus);
size_t data_size = filestatus.st_size;

size_t len = fread(data, 1, data_size , fp);
if (len != data_size) {
    printf("Error reading file %s\n", filename);
    return 0;
}

fclose(fp);
return len;

// free(data) when you are done.
```